# What are the IAM and bucket policies for allowing users to PUT objects only if they come from a S3 bucket source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Currently, S3 GET and PUT actions allow users to upload anything from their local environment into S3 buckets. I am interested in restricting this.

Imagine I have two buckets:

- One called `landing-zone`, which can be used by data engineers to GET and PUT objects from their local environment or all other buckets.
- One called `analysis`, which can only be used by data analysts to PUT objects which originate from the `landing-zone` or `analysis` S3 bucket. (Ideally, analysts would be able to take data from the `landing-zone` or `analysis` S3 bucket, modify it, and PUT it back into `analysis` S3.)

[image]

I created separate access points for the `landing-zone` and `analysis` S3 buckets and then created S3 bucket policies for each, for an analyst user, using the following format.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : 
    [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal" : {"AWS": "arn-user-analyst-name"},
            "Action" : "s3:*",
            "Resource" : "access-point-arn-landing-zone",
            "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"s3:DataAccessPointAccount": "aws-account-id"}}
        }
    ]
}
```

I then created an IAM access policy for analysts with the following S3 permissions.

```json
...
{
            "Sid": "AccessAllS3Settings",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:CreateAccessPoint",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:CreateJob",
                "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
                "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListMultiRegionAccessPoints",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration"
                ],
            "Resource": "*", 
            "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"aws:RequestedRegion": "ap-southeast-2"}}
        },

        {
            "Sid": "GetAllS3Buckets",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion", 
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAttributes",
                "s3:GetObjectAttributes"
                ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::landing-zone",
                "arn:aws:s3:::landing-zone/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::analysis",
                "arn:aws:s3:::analysis/*"
                ], 
            "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"aws:RequestedRegion": "ap-southeast-2"}}
        },

        {
            "Sid": "PutAnalysisS3BucketLimitedBySource",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::analysis",
                "arn:aws:s3:::analysis/*"
                ], 
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {"aws:RequestedRegion": "ap-southeast-2"},
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {"s3:DataAccessPointArn": [
                    "access-point-arn-landing-zone>",
                    "access-point-arn-analysis>"
                    ]}  
                }
        }
...
```

However, when I test this policy as an analyst, copying an existing test dataset from the `landing-zone` to `analysis` S3 bucket fails i.e. `aws s3 cp s3://landing-zone/test.txt s3://analysis/test.txt --sse AES256` produces `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied`.

I can open datasets in the `landing-zone` to `analysis` S3 buckets fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm / clarify the scenario where data analysts can take data from the analysis bucket, modify it, and then put it back...  
  
Do you mean that:  
(OPT A) they must overwrite existing data in the analysis bucket if the source is not from the landing-zone bucket (i.e. retrieve a file from the analysis bucket, and then put it back by overwriting it)  
OR  
(OPT B) the data put back is somehow based on the file that was originally retrieved from the analysis bucket? (if so, can you elaborate on what the acceptable modification of the data is, as this is likely impossible)

Comment: It would be option B. I want to prevent analysts from uploading data directly into the S3 bucket but I also want to allow them access to GET -> PUT scenarios where they take data, perform cleaning and save the cleaned results (i.e. new data files) back inside the analysis bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. With option B in mind, I'm trying to consider how to keep the data within an area that you control so that you can differentiate between data that did originate in the analysis bucket vs data that is from an external source. Could analysts use tools like Athena / Glue / EMR to perform the cleaning? While this certainly wouldn't be fool proof, it may provide enough of an assurance over the provenance of the data (it would really depend on the perimeter that you can construct around those tools too)... would this work for you?

Comment: Great suggestion. I'll test separately granting analyst Glue/EMR access to the landing zone and analysis bucket access points maybe. Direct copying of objects from landing zone to analysis is still disabled but at least analysts can create data pipelines via Glue/EMR and store those outputs into the analysis bucket? Hopefully there's flexibility around the Glue/EMR permissions to do this.

Comment: AWS policies are interesting. They work nicely but there seems to be a gap in 'what happens when people accidentally upload the wrong sensitive data inside S3 buckets?'. The official answer is that the buckets are private I guess, but this isn't always good enough for every organization's risk appetite.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're receiving is for the `CopyObject` action, which isn't the same as `GetObject` or `PutObject`.

If you add `s3:CopyObject` to your actions this should work, but with the current setup *I believe* this would allow the analyst to copy from `landing-zone` to `analysis` and vice versa, which would mean analysts can mess with the data in the `landing-zone`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I added `s3:CopyObject` under the PutAnalysisS3BucketLimitedBySource Sid but the same error message appears. I'm suspecting that the `s3:DataAccessPointArn` condition doesn't do what I think it should do, which is to only allow Put/Copy if the DataAccessPointArn is a specific ARN.